# SSDP & Android, how to reply to a M-SEARCH

Tags: java, android, upnp, dlna, ssdp

When a M-SEARCH command is issued, all the devices that offer a service must reply with the IP address of the service they offer.

My cellphone has 2 interfaces (among others):

- 192.168.1.5: the wifi's interface
- 25.156.35.4: the mobile network interface

Depending on what interface do I receive the M-SEARCH I must reply using the wifi's IP or the mobiel one.

How can I figure out what interface received the request? I am looking for a robust way of doing this. Looking for 192.168... so doesnt look like a good solution.

I listen to the M_SEARCH this way:

```
MulticastSocket clientSocket;                   
clientSocket = new MulticastSocket(1900);
clientSocket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250") );
while(true) 
{

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

    clientSocket.receive(dp);
    final String msg = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());

    if (msg.contains("M-SEARCH")) 
    {
        DatagramSocket resSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);

        String req = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
        req += "LOCATION: http://" + IP_TO_SPECIFY + "/index.html  \r\n";
        req += "HOST: "+android.os.Build.MODEL+"\r\n";
        req += "EXT: \r\n";
        req += "ST: upnp:rootdevice\r\n";
        byte [] sendData = req.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, dp.getAddress(), dp.getPort());
        resSocket.send(sendPacket);
        resSocket.close();
    }                       
}
```

Comment: how are u starting M-Search ?

Answer (score 7):

here is what CheapCast is using :-

```
package com.mobiotics.motionsdk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class SSDP extends Thread {

    /**
     * Default IPv4 multicast address for SSDP messages
     */
    public static final String ADDRESS = "239.255.255.250";

    public static final String IPV6_LINK_LOCAL_ADDRESS = "FF02::C";
    public static final String IPV6_SUBNET_ADDRESS = "FF03::C";
    public static final String IPV6_ADMINISTRATIVE_ADDRESS = "FF04::C";
    public static final String IPV6_SITE_LOCAL_ADDRESS = "FF05::C";
    public static final String IPV6_GLOBAL_ADDRESS = "FF0E::C";

    public static final String ST = "ST";
    public static final String LOCATION = "LOCATION";
    public static final String NT = "NT";
    public static final String NTS = "NTS";

    /* Definitions of start line */
    public static final String SL_NOTIFY = "NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1";
    public static final String SL_MSEARCH = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1";
    public static final String SL_OK = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";

    /* Definitions of notification sub type */
    public static final String NTS_ALIVE = "ssdp:alive";
    public static final String NTS_BYEBYE = "ssdp:byebye";
    public static final String NTS_UPDATE = "ssdp:update";

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "SSDP";

    private SocketAddress mMulticastGroupAddress = new InetSocketAddress("239.255.255.250", 1900);
    private MulticastSocket mMulticastSocket;
    private DatagramSocket mUnicastSocket;

    private NetworkInterface mNetIf;

    private Context mContext;

    private boolean mRunning = false;

    public SSDP(Context ctx) throws IOException {
        mContext = ctx;
        mNetIf = Utils.getActiveNetworkInterface();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        mRunning = true;
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mMulticastSocket = new MulticastSocket(1900);
            mMulticastSocket.setLoopbackMode(true);
            mMulticastSocket.joinGroup(mMulticastGroupAddress, mNetIf);

            mUnicastSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
            mUnicastSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            mUnicastSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Utils.getLocalV4Address(mNetIf),1900));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Setup SSDP failed.", e);
        }
        while(mRunning) {
            DatagramPacket dp = null;
            try {
                dp = receive();

                String startLine = parseStartLine(dp);
                if(startLine.equals(SL_MSEARCH)) {
                    String st = parseHeaderValue(dp, ST);

                    if(st.contains("dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1")) {

                        String responsePayload = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n" +
                                                 "ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1\n"+
                                                 "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\n"+
                                                 "EXT:\n"+
                                                 "CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1800\n"+
                                                 "LOCATION: http://"+Utils.getLocalV4Address(mNetIf).getHostAddress()+":8008/ssdp/device-desc.xml\n" +
                                                 "CONFIGID.UPNP.ORG: 7339\n" +
                                                 "BOOTID.UPNP.ORG: 7339\n" +
                                                 "USN: uuid:"+ Installation.id(mContext)+"\n\n";


                        DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(responsePayload.getBytes(), responsePayload.length(), new InetSocketAddress(dp.getAddress(),dp.getPort()));
                        mUnicastSocket.send(response);

                        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Responding to "+ dp.getAddress().getHostAddress());
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SSDP fail.", e);
            }
        }
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SSDP shutdown.");

    }

    public synchronized void shutdown() {
        mRunning = false;
    }

    private DatagramPacket receive() throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        mMulticastSocket.receive(dp);

        return dp;
    }

    private String parseHeaderValue(String content, String headerName) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(content);
        s.nextLine(); // Skip the start line

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            int index = line.indexOf(':');
            String header = line.substring(0, index);
            if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase(header.trim())) {
                return line.substring(index + 1).trim();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String parseHeaderValue(DatagramPacket dp, String headerName) {
        return parseHeaderValue(new String(dp.getData()), headerName);
    }

    private String parseStartLine(String content) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(content);
        return s.nextLine();
    }

    private String parseStartLine(DatagramPacket dp) {
        return parseStartLine(new String(dp.getData()));
    }
}
```

Comment: where is Utils class defined? Ref link?

Comment: @sribasu you can replace that method call with your own implementation to return current available and active network interface, most-likely it will be wifi

Comment: it's not just a single method, looks like a comprehensive class with lot of utility methods. Do you have an example Utils class link?

Comment: I wrote that Util class, its pretty simple and straight forward, also this code is 9 years old now.